# Org-mode : disable indentation when promoting and demoting trees + subtrees

Tags: org-mode, indentation

In org-mode, when you press `M-S-right` or `M-S-left` to demote or promote a tree with all it's subtrees, the content text is also indented.

So suppose I want to deomote the following structure by two levels, in order to replace it as a part of another tree structure. Then from this:

```
* A
text
** A.I
text
*** A.I.1
text
```

...I get this:

```
*** A
  text
**** A.I
  text
***** A.I.1
  text
```

How can I disable this indentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set the variable `org-adapt-indentation` to `nil`. The default value is `t`, which means:

> When this variable is set, Org assumes that you write outlines by
>   indenting text in each node to align with the headline (after the
>   stars).  The following issues are influenced by this variable:
>
> - The indentation is increased by one space in a demotion
>     command, and decreased by one in a promotion command.  However,
>     in the latter case, if shifting some line in the entry body
>     would alter document structure (e.g., insert a new headline),
>     indentation is not changed at all.

You can change the value via `M-x customize-variable org-adapt-indentation`.

Answer (score 3):

Set variable `org-adapt-indentation` to `nil`.

See also info section (info "(org) Clean View").